# Trying to use HighCharts to build solidgauge chart with multiple layer

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to build some chart like this one:

[Chart Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoNdz.png)

But the main struggle is to add two different series that complement each other.

I really appreciate any help that someone could give me.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it, but the process of implementation is not so easy. I prepared the example which shows how to do that, and I will try to explain what I did, step by step.

First, you need to define your data array just like that:

```
var data = [40, 30, 10, 20]
```

Then define your chart configuration, and inside of `chart.events.load` function handler put whole logic of creating desired effect.

Next step is iterate on all `data` positions, and create its own specific point, series, yAxis and pane, basing on calculations like below:

```
  load() {
    var chart = this,
      series = [],
      panes = [],
      yAxes = [],
      radius = 112,
      innerRadius = 88,
      pointAngle,
      prevPointAngle = 0,
      pointPadding = (radius - innerRadius) / 4,
      colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
      additionalPointPadding = 2;

    data.forEach(function(p, i) {
      pointAngle = (p * 360) / 100 // Calculate point angle

      // Prepare pane for each point
      panes.push({
        startAngle: prevPointAngle + pointPadding + additionalPointPadding,
        endAngle: (pointAngle + prevPointAngle) - pointPadding - additionalPointPadding,
        background: [{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          borderWidth: 0
        }]
      })
      // Prepare yAxis for specific pane
      yAxes.push({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: [],
        pane: i
      })
      // Prepare series with specific point
      series.push({
        name: 'Exercise ' + i,
        data: [{
            color: colors[i],
          radius: radius + '%',
          innerRadius: innerRadius + '%',
          y: 100,
          percents: p
        }],
        yAxis: i
      })
      prevPointAngle += pointAngle
    })
```

And finally, update our chart by new objects:

```
    chart.update({
      pane: panes,
      yAxis: yAxes,
      series: series
    },true, true)
```

Last thing you have to know, that your chart configuration should have the same amount of empty objects in `pane` array, like the data positions, e.g:

```
var data = [10, 80, 10]
(...)
pane: [{},{},{}]
```

Here is the example which shows the final effect: https://jsfiddle.net/yamu5z9r/

Kind regards!